# Why do I get SQL state:23503 when I try to add a constraint to an existing table in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have table `Advisor` which is a special `User`and contains only `id` and `user_id` (for now!) and I'm trying to make `user_id` a foreign key with the following script:

```
ALTER TABLE advisor
ADD CONSTRAINT advisor_user_id_fkey
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES "user" (id);
```

Which I think should work, however I get this error:

```
ERROR: insert or update on table "advisor" violates foreign key constraint "advisor_user_id_fkey"
SQL state: 23503
Detail: Key (user_id)=(44) is not present in table "user".
```

I thinks this is weird because I'm saying it should refer to `user.id` and not `user.user_id`, but obviously I'm doing something wrong. 
Does anyone have any idea about this? Thanks.

**update:** if anyone is wondering why "user" and not user, well pgAdmin doesn't like user, because it thinks it's the owner of the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error message states that *you have an entry in your "advisor" table (44) which does not exist in your "user" table.*

Your Foreign Key is defined on "advisor" and stipulates that the "user" table is the parent table. Perhaps you have that Foreign Key defined backwards?

About the "user" issue, "user" is a reserved word, that's why pgadmin is having trouble with it. If you have the ability to change that, I recommend it. See reserved words at: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html.

Comment: But I'm saying that advisor.user_id should refer to user.id right? That's what the script is saying as far as I know?! I understand the error, I just don't understand why and you are basically telling me what I already understand :)

Comment: Yes, advisor.user_id = user.id. The error says that "user".id has no entries with a value of 44. To check: `SELECT * FROM "user" WHERE id = 44`

Comment: The problem was that advisor was not empty! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here foreign key (user_id) of advisor table pointing to the key (id) of user table.
Check your key(id) of user table exists with the value you are updating in advisor table.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).